# How to detect safe mode on OSX

Tags: c, macos

I have some code that I only want to run if the user didn't boot in safe mode. Is there a way using the CoreFoundation or C standard APIs that I can detect that?

EDIT: here is my code thanks to my accepted answer:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
...

int safeBoot;
int mib_name[2] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_SAFEBOOT };
size_t length = sizeof(safeBoot);

if (!sysctl(mib_name, 2, &safeBoot, &length, NULL, 0)) {
    if (safeBoot == 1) {
        // We are in safe mode
    } else {
        // Normal mode. Continue…
    }
} else {
    // Couldn't find safe boot information
}
```

Comment: How does your code get started in the normal case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sysctl` like this:

```
sysctl -n kern.safeboot
```

It gives `1` when in `safe boot` mode and `0` when in normal mode.