# info cpu on osx with sysctl()

Tags: c++, macos

I am working on osx and i would like to get some info about my cpu. To do that, i found the terminal commande sysctl -a, but i need to get these informations in a programme so i need to use the function systcl();

i tried to read the man but i still have no idea how to get a string with for example the name of my cpu (like the terminal commande sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string)

well i would be very happy for any hint, help or example :D

Comment: See Alex's code here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917371/how-to-detect-safe-mode-on-osx/24918507#24918507

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can do this on my iMac

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFERLEN 128

int main(){
    char buffer[BUFFERLEN];
    size_t bufferlen = BUFFERLEN;
    sysctlbyname("machdep.cpu.brand_string",&buffer,&bufferlen,NULL,0);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

and I get this

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```