# Determine CPU type / architecture in macOS

Tags: macos, apple-silicon

With the upcoming Apple Silicon hardware, some apps may want to determine whether the CPU is an Intel or Apple one.

Which APIs and system calls can provide that information?

As @MarkSetchell [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28026043/2836621), `sysctl -a` can provide some information. For the DTK (macOS 11b3) it returns:

```
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Apple processor
```

OTOH, Apple's `System Profiler.app` shows:

```
Processor Name: Apple A12Z Bionic
```

I like to have a similar result, i.e. rather "Apple A12Z Bionic" than "Apple processor".

A quick search for "Apple A12Z Bionic" on the system volume shows that it appears somewhere in the "dyld_shared_cache_arm64e", but not inside `System Profiler.app`, which suggests that this string is delivered by a framework function rather than being hard-coded in the Profiler app. Therefore, I hope to find the system call that provides this more descriptive name.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/28026043/2836621

Comment: There's a bunch of other stuff you can check out with `sysctl -a | grep -i cpu` in Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

my two cents for swift 5.x (tested in Mac, iOS and.... (NDA rules..))

```
func CPUType() ->Int {
    
    var cputype = UInt32(0)
    var size = cputype.byteWidth
    
    let result = sysctlbyname("hw.cputype", &cputype, &size, nil, 0)
    if result == -1 {
        if (errno == ENOENT){
            return 0
        }
        return -1
    }
    return Int(cputype)
}


let CPU_ARCH_MASK          = 0xff      // mask for architecture bits

let CPU_TYPE_X86           = cpu_type_t(7)
let CPU_TYPE_ARM           = cpu_type_t(12)

func CPUType() ->String {
    
    let type: Int = CPUType()
    if type == -1 {
        return "error in CPU type"
    }
    
    let cpu_arch            = type & CPU_ARCH_MASK
    
    if cpu_arch == CPU_TYPE_X86{
        return "X86"
    }
    
    if cpu_arch == CPU_TYPE_ARM{
        return "ARM"
    }
    
    return "unknown"
}
```

// accessory f.:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var byteWidth:Int {
        return self.bitWidth/UInt8.bitWidth
    }
    static var byteWidth:Int {
        return Self.bitWidth/UInt8.bitWidth
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a slight bug in your code. You're using the mask incorrectly. The way you mask it, you need to mask the lower 24 bits, not just the 8 bits that you mask. The 0xff000000 mask in my code is for getting the arch bits. While your code currently works, because all codes are still below 256, it's not really correct as Apple intends it.

Comment: OMG... I will fix. ;(

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggest, the `sysctl` function can be used to identify the CPU type (but not deliver the "Apple A12Z Bionic" text I am seeking).

Here's a code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    uint32_t cputype = 0;
    size_t size = sizeof (cputype);
    int res = sysctlbyname ("hw.cputype", &cputype, &size, NULL, 0);
    if (res) {
        printf ("error: %d\n", res);
    } else {
        printf ("cputype: 0x%08x\n", cputype);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `0x00000007` on an Intel Mac, and `0x0100000c` on a Apple Silicon DTK (as of BigSur beta 3).

The `01` in the most significant byte is a flag indicating an ARM 64 bit system. Defined in `machine.h`:

```
#define CPU_ARCH_MASK           0xff000000      /* mask for architecture bits */
#define CPU_ARCH_ABI64          0x01000000      /* 64 bit ABI */
#define CPU_ARCH_ABI64_32       0x02000000      /* ABI for 64-bit hardware with 32-bit types; LP32 */

#define CPU_TYPE_X86            ((cpu_type_t) 7)
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM            ((cpu_type_t) 12)
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM64          (CPU_TYPE_ARM | CPU_ARCH_ABI64)
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM64_32       (CPU_TYPE_ARM | CPU_ARCH_ABI64_32)
```

See also: [macOS CPU Architecture (Ohanaware)](https://www.ohanaware.com/blog/202032/macOS-CPU-Architecture.html)

Comment: pls dont write if (cputype).. as apple sates: "Never assume the numerical value of a BOOL is anything other than 0 or 1."      At:    https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/addressing_architectural_differences_in_your_macos_code

Comment: Oh, but by C's definition, "if (x)" tests for != 0, so this is totally fine. Also, you mean "if (res)", not "if (cputype)", right? What Apple means is that you should not assume that a BOOL can be -1, for instance. In that regard, I'm doing the safest test possible. And my test does not even involve the BOOL type. So, all's well.

Comment: I always thought as You,  -33 mena TRUE (as CPU will consider Zero Flag, but Appel notice did scared me :))

Comment: Seems this sysctl function programmatically under Rosetta returns type 0x00000007 (X86) rather than type 0x0100000C (ARM64) which the command line produces.

Answer (score 1):

Working for me.

Reference Sources:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678914

```swift
var systeminfo = utsname()
uname(&systeminfo)
let machine = withUnsafeBytes(of: &systeminfo.machine) {bufPtr->String in
    let data = Data(bufPtr)
    if let lastIndex = data.lastIndex(where: {$0 != 0}) {
        return String(data: data[0...lastIndex], encoding: .isoLatin1)!
    } else {
        return String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1)!
    }
}
// arm64
print(machine)
```

The result:

[image]